# Convert Recycler View with GridLayoutManager to Pdf

Tags: android, gridview, pdf-generation

I am using following code to generate pdf from Recycler view,

```
         public void generatePDF(RecyclerView view) {
        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();
       Bitmap bigBitmap = null;
        if (adapter != null) {
            int size = adapter.getItemCount();
            int height = 0;
            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);
            // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
            LruCache<String, Bitmap> bitmaCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i));
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i);
            holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight());
                holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap drawingCache = holder.itemView.getDrawingCache();
                if (drawingCache != null) {
                    bitmaCache.put(String.valueOf(i), drawingCache);
                }
                height += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas bigCanvas = new Canvas(bigBitmap);
            bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4);
            final File file = new File(getStorageDir(), "A.pdf");
            try {
                PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(file));
            } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                try {
                    //Adding the content to the document
                    Bitmap bmp = bitmaCache.get(String.valueOf(i));
                    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
                    image.scalePercent(85);
                    image.setAlignment(Image.LEFT);
                    if (!document.isOpen()) {
                        document.open();
                    }
                    document.add(image);

                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.e("TAG-ORDER PRINT ERROR", ex.getMessage());
                }
            }
            if (document.isOpen()) {
                document.close();
            }
        // Set on UI Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                    builder.setTitle("Success")
                        .setMessage("PDF File Generated Successfully.")
                        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }).show();


                }
            });

        }

    }
```

This is code is working well when I am generating pdf from recyclerview with LinearLayoutManager but when I am using GridLayoutmanager with 3 item in each row is not print the item as looking in recylerview. Actually the output is same in both with LinearLayoutManage and GirdLayoutManager. But my requirement is to print pdf from the recyclerview with GridLayoutManager that has 3 item in each row. So please help me to short out my problem.

Comment: can you show your recyclerview code where you have used Grid layout manager

Comment: mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();

        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");

        list.add("D");
        list.add("E");
        list.add("F");
        

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
       GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        List<String> list = new ArrayList();

        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
        list.add("C");

        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

Comment: In the provided code, you are saving the item views of Recyclerview inside a cache and then converting the bitmap inside the cache to an image and adding it to the document with the alignment as LEFT. In this case the recyclerview layout wont interfere into the document creation as you are pulling out each itemviews and creating the document structure yourself. Please check if the document.add(image); can place the images side by side.

Comment: Also can you please provide the libraries you have used?

Comment: Sir please give me a code snippets through which i can achieve my goal.

Comment: compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'

Comment: I am using above library

Comment: bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                    byte a[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    byte b[] = stream.toByteArray();
                    stream.write(a);
                    stream.write(b);
                    Image image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());

Comment: Unable to get out put as like i want

Comment: @Rameez Thattarath sir

Comment: What change are you trying to make now??

Comment: I have tried to combine two byte[]

Comment: One way to achive this is by creating a View with two itemviews   here...      for (i in 0 until size) {
                val holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i))
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i)
                holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.width/2, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED))
                holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.measuredWidth/2,

Comment: then getting object of Image by using Image.getInstance(byte[]) on this combined array

Comment: explain more if you can please

Comment: I have already tried sir

Comment: Any body can help??

Answer (score 0):

Do this :-

```
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvNumbers);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
    List<String> list = new ArrayList(); list.add("A"); list.add("B"); list.add("C");
    MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

Comment: have you removed these lines and replace to my answer because I have faced that same issue :   mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); GridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3); mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

Comment: But issue is remain same.

Comment: void setAdapter() {
        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 3));
        List<String> list = new ArrayList(); list.add("A"); list.add("B"); list.add("C");
        MyAdapter myAdapter = new MyAdapter(this, list);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    }

Comment: do one experiment use your old code and remove mine in that code user linearlayoutmanager as a orientation of horizontal let see it catches horizontal view or not

Comment: do this in java not in xml

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Comment: do as horizontally

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Now this is my xml

Comment: But issue is remain same

Comment: i said do a experiment using linear layout manager as horizontally

Comment: mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true));

Comment: in pdf, is data coming as horizontally?

Comment: No Sir, data is always coming vertically

Comment: can you share link of pdf in screenshot

Comment: Do one thing first try to display data in sample activity, check that activity that layoutmanager is working propely or not

Comment: I am still facing this issue.